# How to use OUT cursors into procedures in Yii? Oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, yii

I don't know how to bind the cursor parameter to the statement. Below is standard php which works:

```
$conn = oci_connect("hr", "hrpwd", "localhost/XE");
$curs = oci_new_cursor($conn);
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "begin myproc(:cursbv); end;");
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":cursbv", $curs, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
oci_execute($stid);
oci_execute($curs);
```

The Yii version:

```
$connection=Yii::app()->dbStandardConnection;
$sql="begin myproc(:cursbv); end;";
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$command->bindParam(":cursbv",$curs,??);
$command->execute();
```

As you can see I have put instead of the third parameter in bindParam, ?? because I don't know the type.
I have tried doing this several ways, using different types but can't seem to get it to work.
My database has a lot of procedures using cursors and I want to use Yii's data access objects to use them.

Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: I gave you the the link to the oracle docs. You can do it on your own.

Comment: You are not helping. Can't you see that my question is based on similar docs? I have already tried and I have failed, over and over again. I am now looking for someone that knows and has done this before. @zaratustra

Comment: @DincăAlexandru I just read that `PDO_OCI` does not support cursors! And looks like it has been idle in experimental phase for a long time! No official reference I have but for this [discussion forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26548-experience-with-oracle/)

Answer (score 0):

`PDO::oci` does not support REF CURSORS.
Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php

But for Yii there is a workaround by using oci8 which supports cursors and is well supported by Yii.

Yii has oci8 extensions. Which makes using oci8 easier and its better in terms of performance compared to `pdo_oci`.
Reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/oci8pdo